# Are there situations in which ssh -t shouldn't be used?

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, ssh, openssh

Working within a framework commands are issued to remote machines using ssh.  Recently the -t option was added to the command in order to get it to work properly with sudo.  However this option will be enabled for all remote commands as well.

Before submitting this change into the code base I was wondering if there are any situations in which having the -t option will cause issues with the usage of ssh?

Answer (score 1):

The manpage of `ssh` on Debian Wheezy gives, among other things:

> If no pseudo-tty has been allocated, the session is transparent and can be used to reliably transfer binary data.  On most systems, setting the escape character to “none” will also make the session transparent even if a tty is used.

That is, if you want to transfer data (`cat file | ssh host executable_that_reads_input`), you likely want to avoid `-t`, unless your data is plain-text only.

Comment: scp is used to transfer binary data to the machine before attempting to read it, so this shouldn't be an issue for us, +1 for the good response though.